# Quickly using up all connections on postgresql in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, pg

I am using an app on GCP with Node.js with Postgresql (Cloud SQL, lowest tier i.e. 25 connections) using the 'pg' package ("pg": "^8.7.3",). I am quite new with this configuration so there may be some very basic errors here.

I configure my `pg_client` like this

```
// CLOUD SQL POSTGRESQL DATABASE
const { Client, Pool } = require('pg')
const pg_client = new Pool({
  user: process.env.PG_USER,
  host: process.env.PG_HOST,
  database: process.env.PG_DB,
  password: process.env.PG_PWD,
  port: 5432,
})
```

and then, in order to copy the data from a nosql-database with some 50.000+ items I go through them pretty much like this. I know the code doesn't make perfect sense but this is how the SQL calls are being made:

```
fiftyThoussandOldItems.forEach(async (item) => {
  let nameId = await pg_client.query("SELECT id from some1000items where name='John'")
  pg_client.query("INSERT into items (id, name, url) VALUES (nameId, 1,2)"
})
```

This does however quickly render `sorry, too many clients already :: proc.c:362` and `error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`.

I have done similar runs before without experiencing this issue (but then with about 1000 items).

As far as I understand, I do **Not** need to do a pg_client.connect() and pg_client.release() (or is it .end()) any longer, according to a SO-answer I unfortunately can't find any longer. Is this really correct? (When I tried to before, I ended up with a lot of other issues that causes other types of problems)

So, my questions are:

- What am I doing wrong? Do I need to use pg_client.connect() before every SQL-call and then pg_client.release() after every SQL-call? Or is it pg_client.end()?
- Is there a way to have this automatically handled? It doesn't seem very DRY and bug prone.

Comment: For this kind of operations it's better acquire client from a Pool and release it after work is done. Pool is released automagically but it takes time to finish transaction, so you have a lot of clients used for one loop. And most importand one, pool query is not transaction save. Every insert is separate transaction. So better get client from pool `const client = await pool.connect()` , do work on client and release it after loop `client.release()`.

Comment: Also no need to separate query just to acquire nameId. You can use `insert into ...  select` or use subselect in insert statement.

Comment: @Kadet Thanks! I tried this for this particular query and it seems like it may work, but I am confused to when to use connect/release and when I can just do a pg_client.query()? Is it long-running looped queries like this one when I should do connect/release?

Comment: Good idea considering insert into ... select, I forgot about that!

Comment: pool.query (as in documentation) is good for one select. If there is many inserts and selects in block it's better to acquire client for this job and do it on one client, and after that release it.